# Apticron don't send e-mail

Tags: ubuntu

My host can send e-mail, i set ssmtp,but apticron don't send.

Configuration is default.   i just set EMAIL=myaddress@gmil and set /etc/cron.d/apticrono

(17 * * * * root if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron --cron; else true; fi)

Every hourlys send one e-mail,but nothing happened

So i check syslog it show
CMD (if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron --cron; else true; fi)

It don't send e-mail for my e-mail address

How to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where i didn't get any emails from Apticron,
I configured Mailx and made a small change to the Apticron code and it worked.

Configure Mailx, you can follow the instruction here:
https://coderwall.com/p/ez1x2w/send-mail-like-a-boss

And then change the Apticron code (/usr/sbin/apticron) so it will use the account you configured in the above link (-A gmail)

Mailx() {
        if [ "x`readlink -e /usr/bin/mailx`" = "x/usr/bin/heirloom-mailx" ]
        then
                # heirloom-mailx creates correct headers, but needs help
                # if the terminal charset (LC_CTYPE) is no UTF-8 locale
        if [ -n "$CUSTOM_FROM" ] ; then
                        /usr/bin/mailx **-A gmail** -S ttycharset=utf-8 -r "$CUSTOM_FROM" "$@"
                else
                        /usr/bin/mailx **-A gmail** -S ttycharset=utf-8 "$@"
                fi
        else
                # bsd-mailx/mailutils' mailx don't do character set
                # conversion, but do not support MIME either.
                if [ -n "$CUSTOM_FROM" ] ; then
                        /usr/bin/mailx **-A gmail** -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" \
                                -a "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" \
                                -a "Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit" \
                                -a "From: $CUSTOM_FROM" \
                                "$@"
                else
                        /usr/bin/mailx **-A gmail** -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" \
                                -a "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" \
                                -a "Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit" \
                                "$@"
                fi
        fi